# trying to run cli "ng lint" in an ng2 app not genned from cli

Tags: angular, lint

I have an ng2 app integrated in a .NET MVC app.  I've structured the parent and child app to work together.  I'm able to exec the cli "ng build" to build the nested ng2 app successfully.  However, I'm having problems getting "ng lint" working.

"ng lint" works as expected on the ng2 app that I ng new'd with the cli. I copied over the tslint.json to my integrated app and when I run ng lint, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'tslint' from 'C:\CODE\MySite'
Error: Cannot find module 'tslint' from 'C:\CODE\MySite'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (C:\CODE\MySite\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:33:11)
    at Object.requireProjectModule (C:\CODE\MySite\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\require-project-module.js:6:28)
    at Class.run (C:\CODE\MySite\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\lint.js:30:49)
    at Class.run (C:\CODE\MySite\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\lint.js:46:25)
    at resolve (C:\CODE\MySite\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:273:20)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.validateAndRun (C:\CODE\MySite\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:251:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\CODE\MySite\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:154:24)
    at <anonymous>
```

Any idea what the problem might be here or how to debug?

Comment: can you upload the content of your package.json?

Comment: i put the package.json in this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/obhhcFJchkHIl5SDqtfM?p=catalogue